# Android Studio for Mac crashes on startup

Tags: macos, android-studio, crash, startup, osx-yosemite

I downloaded Android Studio 2.3 and installed. Then I tried to open the app and it did "quit unexpectedly" before even starting up.

This is the result I got for `$ /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio`.

```
2017-03-23 19:40:03.869 studio[5988:353457] Value of STUDIO_JDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk
2017-03-23 19:40:03.871 studio[5988:353457] allVms required 1.8*,1.8+
2017-03-23 19:40:03.873 studio[5988:353468] fullFileName is: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2017-03-23 19:40:03.874 studio[5988:353468] fullFileName exists: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2017-03-23 19:40:03.874 studio[5988:353468] Value of STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS is (null)
2017-03-23 19:40:03.874 studio[5988:353468] Processing VMOptions file at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2017-03-23 19:40:03.875 studio[5988:353468] Done
2017-03-23 19:40:03.875 studio[5988:353468] Processing VMOptions file at /Users/chevindu/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.3/studio.vmoptions
2017-03-23 19:40:03.877 studio[5988:353468] No content found
2017-03-23 19:40:03.877 studio[5988:353468] Processing VMOptions file at 
2017-03-23 19:40:03.878 studio[5988:353468] No content found
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/idea.properties: 'java.endorsed.dirs' already defined
Looking in classpath from com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader@5c29bfd for /com/sun/jna/darwin/libjnidispatch.jnilib
Found library resource at jar:file:/Applications/Android%20Studio.app/Contents/lib/jna.jar!/com/sun/jna/darwin/libjnidispatch.jnilib
Trying /Users/chevindu/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio2.3/tmp/jna7329126360829887390.tmp
Found jnidispatch at /Users/chevindu/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio2.3/tmp/jna7329126360829887390.tmp
Looking for library 'c'
Adding paths from jna.library.path: null
Trying libc.dylib
Found library 'c' at libc.dylib
Looking for library 'Foundation'
Adding paths from jna.library.path: null
Trying libFoundation.dylib
Adding system paths: [/usr/lib, /usr/lib]
Trying libFoundation.dylib
Looking for matching frameworks
Trying /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
Found library 'Foundation' at /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
[   9207]   WARN - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /private/var/folders/m3/9bsc3x6s2vq8z50zh24c1g9w0000gn/T/StudioDownloadersys-img2-1.xml (No such file or directory) 
[   9995]   WARN - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - File /Users/chevindu/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded. 
[  10051]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /private/var/folders/m3/9bsc3x6s2vq8z50zh24c1g9w0000gn/T/StudioDownloader1addon2-1.xml (No such file or directory) 
[  10051]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - File /Users/chevindu/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded. 
[  10117]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - No Android SDK Found 
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff87706f72, pid=5988, tid=0x0000000000000513
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_112-b06) (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.112-b06 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsystem_c.dylib+0xf72]  strlen+0x12
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/chevindu/java_error_in_studio_5988.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Abort trap: 6
```

I have Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13) installed and OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 running.

This is the result I got for `$ printenv`.

```
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
TMPDIR=/var/folders/m3/9bsc3x6s2vq8z50zh24c1g9w0000gn/T/Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.AvWjd1Ew1S/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=343.7
TERM_SESSION_ID=CEC1537E-091C-4099-9C40-D933AF826E27
USER=chevindu
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.l8xDQvW92n/Listeners
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PWD=/Users/chevindu
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/chevindu
STUDIO_JDK=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk
LOGNAME=chevindu
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

You can read the error log at `/Users/chevindu/java_error_in_studio_5988.log` from [here](https://justpaste.it/javaerrorlog).

Any help on this matter is very much appreciated.

Comment: Also post the error log found at the location `/Users/chevindu/java_error_in_studio_5988.log`

Comment: @Isuru - Please checkout the log at here: https://justpaste.it/javaerrorlog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Known Bug?

This may be related to a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=237590) which, according to [one comment](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=237590#c11), *should* be fixed in the next minor version (2.3.1).

There are workarounds and interim solutions described in the issue, including downgrading java or downloading and replacing a binary in the Android Studio app. (I personally haven't tried them, but feel free to comment directly on the issue if it works for you.)

Comment: I tried replacing the binary file mentioned in that forum, and it worked like a charm! This was bothering me for weeks now, I cannot thank you enough. Hope the issue will get resolved in the next update.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded another version, copied studio from Contents/macos/studio and pasted it on my new bugged version; I replaced the studio file.

It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This works 100%

I have been dealing with this for a week and i found the solution to not loose my data

Restart you mac and on startup press and hold "Shift" key

It will launch in safe mode , Then open Android studio once and close it

Restart again to go exist safe mode and open Android studio

Hope works for you